# Javascript variable as property setting for jwplayer

Tags: javascript, variables, jwplayer

HELP!! i need to use a variable for the property "file" but cant find any documentation on the proper syntax.

if i have:

```
var video="**URL TO MY VIDEO**";
```

then i need something like this:

```
jwplayer("movieContainer").setup({
autostart: true,
flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
skin: "jwplayer/lulu.zip",
height: 270,
width: 480,
file: **video** *<<<< I NEED VAR VIDEO TO PRINT HERE*
});
```

please help!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 4):

It's actually very simple -- just put the variable where you'd put the string.

```
jwplayer("movieContainer").setup({
    autostart: true,
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
    skin: "jwplayer/lulu.zip",
    height: 270,
    width: 480,
    file: video
});
```

Comment: @Max you actually have the solution in your question :)

Comment: @Max Don't put it in quotes. Just put the variable name in, unenclosed, as in my answer.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick answer!

I thought it would be that easy at first too, but unfortunately it doesnt work.  

When entered in as just **video** (no quotes) it acts as if the js is broken and does not load.

When in quotes **"video"** the player returns "stream undefined".
It does however let me echo a php variable in there ("<?php echo $myVariable ?>") as long as thats in quotes.  I need it to be dynamic however and it cannot refresh the page.  

help please!!! THANKS AGAIN!!!

Comment: @Max In that case, there's more to your code than you've shown. Could you post the whole thing, perhaps in [a pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/).

Comment: it looks like its because the jwplayer setup is doing some weird flashvars thing and wont let me use another javascript variable inside of it.  so instead of trying to replace that one piece, i wrote the whole chunk into a js function and then print it with the innerHTML call on a click action. _example:_ `document.getElementById("playerCode").innerHTML=video2();` 

this way i can store the file url in a php variable and then echo that in each different js function that gets called by its corresponding button.  this way i can load the videos dynamically!!
Thanks again though!!

Comment: @MaxRyanSupera - looks like you solved it - you should put the above comment into a new answer (and then "accept" it as the correct answer). You're allowed to answer your own questions! It also means that later, if somebody has the same problem - if they see your question, they know that there is a real solution to the problem.

Comment: Also - you might want to edit the question and add the extra info about the "weird flashvars" too - so the question is complete :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
jwplayer("movieContainer").setup({
    autostart: true,
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
    skin: "jwplayer/lulu.zip",
    height: 270,
    width: 480,
    file: video,
});
```